# python argparse, input output pairs

Tags: python, argparse

Looking for a pattern for `argparse` that would support a series of input/output file pairs:

For example:

```bash
app.py --input FOO.txt_in --output FOO.txt_out \
       --input BAR.txt_in --output BAR.txt.Out
```

In effect, each "--input" file must be paired with an "--output" file
and there must be 1 in/out pair, but can have multiples

Google is failing me - cause what I am finding is argparse tutorials and not what I am looking for.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html pay attention to `action` and `nargs`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use append and match the resulting lists:

```
parser = argprse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--input', action='append')
parser.add_argument('--output', action='append')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

`args.input` and `args.output` are now lists (but you can provide them how you've written in the question), and you can zip them together. You can assert that they have the same length as a check, and you can safely assume that users will read your help message before trying to use the commandline, so add a help message to explain how this works You can say something like:

> The ith input corresponds to the ith output